# $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'] empty with mod_auth_digest enabled

Tags: apache2, php, authentication

The output from sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Seems to indicate that the digest auth module is working on my server, but when I try to access $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'], the variable doesn't exist.

My virtualhost setup is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sam
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sam/public/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/sam-error.log

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

        <Directory /var/www/sam/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                #AuthType Digest
                #AuthName "api"
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Apache configuration, you've not enabled [Digest authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html). Try uncommenting the relevant lines and restart Apache through `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sam
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sam/public/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/sam-error.log

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

        <Directory /var/www/sam/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AuthType Digest
                AuthName "api"
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If this did not work or gives a server error, check the error log in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`.

If you implement Digest authentication, you may want to check the [digest authentication example on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#example-316). A description of all `$_SERVER` variables can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).